# Проблема с внесением данных в базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

После нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить" следующий срабатывает метод:

```
protected function obr(){

        if (!empty($_FILES['img_src']['tmp_name'])){
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_src']['tmp_name'],'img/'.$_FILES['img_src']['name'])){
                exit("Не удалось загрузить изображение");
            }

            $img_src = 'img/'.$_FILES['img_src']['name'];

        }else{
            exit("Необходимо загрузить изображение");
        }

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d", time());
        $discription = $_POST['discription'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];

        if (empty($title) || empty($text) || empty($discription)){
            exit("Не заполненны обязательные поля");
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO statii 
                        (title, img_src, date, text, discription, cat)
                      VALUES ('$title', '$img_src', '$date', '$text', '$discription, '$cat')";

        if(!mysql_query($query)){
            exit("Ошибка ввода в базу данных".mysql_error());    
        }else{
            $_SESSION['res'] = "Изменения внесены успешно";
            header("Location:?option=add_statii");
            exit();
        }    
    }
```

Работа завершается здесь:

```
if(!mysql_query($query)){
        exit("Ошибка ввода в базу данных".mysql_error());    
}
```

Ошибка на экране: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTIv7.png

В чем заключается моя проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Одинарная кавычка в конце `$discription` пропущена при составлении запроса.

Также, возможно, нужна точка с запятой после запроса.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы пропустили " ' " в куске кода `'$text', '$discription', '$cat')"`, около `$description` - по этому он кидает синтакситечкую ошибку.
2. И у вас никогда не выполнится запрос, потому что в функция [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) принимает два параметра: `mysql_query($sql, $connection)`, где `$connection` - ваш коннект к базе, который вы не указали и скорее всего даже не инициализировали.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильно сформирован запрос, необходимо восстановить кавычку (привести к такому формату)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO statii 
            (title, img_src, date, text, discription, cat)
            VALUES ('$title', '$img_src', '$date', '$text', '$discription', '$cat')";
```